# Why increasing bridge ratio improve efficiency?

Tags: efficiency, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

From *The Bonded Electrical Resistance Strain Gage* by Murray & Miller where it says:

> For operation with a single gage, and under some conditions with two
> gauges, the efficiency can be improved by increasing the bridge ratio.
> There is relatively little to be gained, however, but going beyond a
> ratio of about 10, which will yield approximately 90% of the ultimate.
> Many investigators prefer to use a maximum value of 5 which allows
> considerably lower voltage for the power supply with an efficiency
> that is above 80%.

What exactly does that mean? If I have a single strain gauge of \$ R_1 = 350 \Omega \$ and a constant voltage supply \$ V_{EX} = 5V \$,

**Then for bridge ratio of 5:**

\$ I_{\text{ratio of 5}} = {{V} \over {(R_1 + R_2)}} = {5 \over ((350*5) + 350)} = 23.8mA \$

\$ I_{\text{ratio of 1}} = {5 \over (350+350)} = 71.4mA \$ .

Since power dissipation is \$ \propto I^2 \$, the ratio of their efficiency and voltage drop would be

\$ { ({I_{\text{ratio of 5}}})^2 \over ({I_{\text{ratio of 1}}})^2} = {23.8mA^2 \over 71.4mA^2} = 11 \% \$

\$ { ({V_{\text{ratio of 5}}}) \over ({V_{\text{ratio of 1}}})} = {{23.8mA*350 \Omega} \over {71.4mA*350 \Omega}} = 33 \% \$

**And for bridge ratio of 10** (\$ R_2 = 10 * R_1 = 3500 \Omega \$), I'll get

\$ { ({I_{\text{ratio of 10}}})^2 \over ({I_{\text{ratio of 1}}})^2} = {1.3mA^2 \over 71.4mA^2} = 0.03 \% \$

\$ { ({V_{\text{ratio of 10}}}) \over ({V_{\text{ratio of 1}}})} = {{1.3mA*350 \Omega} \over {71.4mA*350 \Omega}} = 1.8 \% \$

- If I go for a ratio of 10, the strain gauge \$ R_1 \$ dissipates only 0.03% power than that in a bridge ratio of 1 - hence the circuit has reached an efficiency of 99.07%! That certainly not `relatively little to be gain ... going beyond a ratio of about 10` stated in the textbook. I think I'm misunderstanding something here.
- At bridge ratio of 5, the voltage drop of the strain gauge \$ R_1 \$ is 67% lower than its drop in a 1:1 bridge ratio, but that has no implication that it `allows considerably lower voltage for the power supply` other than knowing it will take on a lower voltage drop just because a bigger resistance consumes a larger share of the supply voltage. Again, what does that statement means?

[image: wheatstone bridge]

Comment: Honestly, "efficiency" is rather strange word to use here IMO. Since there is no real power output. "Power consumption" would be more apt I think. Look more carefully when you say "*hence the circuit has reached an efficiency of 99.07%!*" That doesn't make sense. If I use 1% the amount of power that you do, it doesn't make me 99% efficient. It makes me 9900% *more* efficient than you though. They probably have a target voltage for the bridge output. 5V for 1V output seems reasonable. 10V source for 1V is starting to push it. 20V~100V source for 1V output...that seems like lot of extra work

Comment: @DKNguyen exactly. If I target 1V output, that would require a higher voltage supply for a bigger bridge ratio (bigger total resistance) - that would make it less efficient instead. If I don't consider linearity and strictly in terms of efficient, I would to have a lower bridge ratio (or lower total resistance) instead. But the book states otherwise without explaining any further hence my question here

Comment: "*I don't consider linearity and strictly in terms of efficient, I would to have a lower bridge ratio (or lower total resistance) instead.*" Huh? Did you mean to say what you typed and not the complete opposite?

Comment: I wonder if the author is referring to measurable voltage change versus gauge resistance change as 'efficiency'? In the limit of an infinite ratio, ie a single gauge driven by a current source, dV/V = dR/R. When in ratio with the same value resistor, dV/V = 0.5dR/R, it's half as sensitive. Large ratios approach the current source limit.

Comment: @Neil_UK Oh maybe. That would make sense.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I meant what I typed. For ratio of 1, if I target an output of 1V, current through R1 is 2.86mA and voltage supply has to be 2V.  For ratio of 5, supply voltage has to be 6V to maintain 1V output and 2.86mA through R1.  I'll need 11V for ratio of 10! The maintain 1V output, I'll need higher voltage supply for bigger ratio.

Comment: See page 111 of your book. Efficiency is not power efficiency, it is defined as output per unit strain of your arrangement divided by output per unit strain of the gage (i.e a constant current circuit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$Bridge\ Ratio = \frac {R_2} {R_1} = \frac {R_3} {R_4} = a$$

You are confusing electrical efficiency vs efficiency of the strain gage.

From p111:

> The circuit efficiency, \$\eta\$, of a particular circuit may be expressed as the ratio of its maximum output, per unit of strain, to the corresponding value for the constant-current circuit that produces the maximum obtainable output.

$$\eta = \frac {a} {1+a}\ \ \ (4.36)$$

So if a = 1 (all resistances are equal), the efficiency will be 50%.  a = 10, efficiency = 90.9%, a = 5, 83.3% (above 80%) and a = \$\infty\$, efficiency = 100%.

If \$R_3\$ >> \$R_4\$ (a strain gage), then \$\Delta R_4\$ has smaller impact on current, so essentially constant-current circuit.  Essentially, with a constant-current source, the change in voltage \$\Delta V_4\$ = change in strain.  A Bridge Ratio of 5 is enough to make the results linear.

The higher the bridge ratio, the more linear the circuit.

[image]